# SVN: preventing a sub-dir updating?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

My repo has one dir containing some very large files, every time those get changed it wastes a few minutes of my day when I update... they're not files I need.

Perhaps ideally they'd be in their own repo, but that's not an option to me... is there a way I can make SVN not include that dir when I update the whole working dir, but wtill allow me to manually update that sub-dir if I want to every week or so?

Preferably using Tortoise rather than command-line...

ps: I tried using ignore but it for some reason seemed to delete the sub-dir... though that might be me doing it wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Subversion 1.6 added a new feature, called [Spare Directory Exclusion](http://subversion.tigris.org/svn_1.6_releasenotes.html#sparse-directory-exclusion) (which is even better than the --depth from 1.5), as you can directly specifiy, which directory you don't want to update in one single command.

```
svn update --set-depth=exclude www
```

Examples to be found [in the blog](http://blogs.open.collab.net/svn/2009/03/sparse-directories-now-with-exclusion.html).

I really don't know how this would work in Tortoise (and I assume that it's not possible).

Comment: it is possible in TSVN. Try the "Update to Revision" command. Then select the directories you do/don't want. It will "remove" the unchecked directories from your working copy!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can using Subversion's new (version 1.5) [`--depth` feature](http://subversion.tigris.org/svn_1.5_releasenotes.html#sparse-checkouts). You can do it like this:

- Check out your project root directory with `--depth immediates`
- For all directories *except* the one you want to exclude, check out those directories with no `--depth` option (or equivalently, `--depth infinity`)

Subversion will remember your depth preferences so when you do an `update` from the project root directory, the directory you omitted (with the large files) will be skipped.

TortoiseSVN also supports the [checkout depth](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-checkout.html#tsvn-dug-checkout-depth) from within the GUI.

Note also that although a version 1.5 or later Subversion client will support the above options, in order to work efficiently the *server* must also be updated to version 1.5 or later. Otherwise, since the server doesn't understand the `--depth` request, the client will ask for everything and filter out the updates on the client side. Obviously this wouldn't solve your problem of updates taking too long.

Answer (score 1):

could you not just add a svn:ignore?